# How to set different Label in Legend in Pie Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, pie-chart, mschart

I'm currently doing a window form that have `Pie Chart` inside.I need to show the percentage of the pie.

But now I have eencountered a problem : When I add this `#PERCENT{P2}` to series the `Pie Chart` will show like this:

[image]

But if I remove it, the `Pie Chart` will show like this

[image]

Is there possible to make the `Pie Chart` Like this?[image]

My Code：

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("completed", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("no", typeof(int));
        int noin = allitem - intime;
        dt.Rows.Add("Complete In Time", intime);
        dt.Rows.Add("OverDue", noin);

        chart1.DataSource = dt;

        chart1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is easily done by setting the `LegendText` for each of your `DataPoints` like this:

```
foreach (DataPoint dp in yourSeries.Points) dp.LegendText = yourLabel;
```

If your x-values contain meaningful numbers you can use them:

```
foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points) dp.LegendText = dp.XValue + "";
```

But if you added the x-values as **strings** they are **lost** and you have to use another source for the `LegendTexts`.

If you only have a fixed number of `DataPoints` you can set the `LegendTexts` directly:

```
yourSeries.Points[0].LegendText = "hi";
yourSeries.Points[1].LegendText = "ho";
yourSeries.Points[2].LegendText = "hum";
```

Note that usually a `Legend` shows one entry per `Series`. But for a `Pie` chart it shows one entry per `DataPoint`!

Comment: I Just now only know that item is call legend text , Thank you